# Assignment to scope isn't working in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive below that makes a change in the scope element `sections.data` which i later `assign` to update the data on UI. However, this approach works in the function `change_subnav` but not in the switch case (added the comments to code). Why is this happening? The code to this change is same. Will appreciate any help here. Please let me know if I need to add more information.

**Plunker-** https://embed.plnkr.co/wmoJcQ/

```
.directive('selectSubnav', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            var change_subnav = function (subnav) {
                if (scope.active_tab == 'user_exercises') {
                    var sections = {};
                    sections[subnav] = scope[scope.active_tab][subnav];
                    // this works
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        $parse('sections.data').assign(scope.$parent, sections);
                    });
                } else {

                }
            };

            $(element).on('click', function () {
                $(element).parent().children().removeClass('active');
                $(element).addClass('active');

                switch (attr.selectSubnav) {
                    case 'All':
                        // this doesn't work
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            $parse('sections.data').assign(scope.$parent, scope[scope.active_tab]);
                            console.log(scope.sections.data);
                        });

                        break;
                    default:
                        change_subnav(attr.selectSubnav);
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**UPDATE**

```
.directive('selectSubnav', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var currentScope = scope;
            var change_subnav = function (subnav) {
                if (scope.active_tab == 'user_exercises') {
                    var sections = {};
                    sections[subnav] = scope[scope.active_tab][subnav];
                } else {

                }

                return sections;
            };

            $(element).on('click', function () {
                $(element).parent().children().removeClass('active');
                $(element).addClass('active');

                var sections;

                switch (attr.selectSubnav) {
                    case 'All':
                        // this doesn't work
                        sections = currentScope[currentScope.active_tab];
                        break;
                    default:
                        sections = change_subnav(attr.selectSubnav);
                        break;
                }

                currentScope.$apply(function () {
                    $parse('sections.data').assign(currentScope.$parent, sections);
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: A plunker with your html and controller code for context would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I've added the plunker. Tried to replicate the scenario as far as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have access to scope in your link function, so instead of updating scope.sections.data like this:

```
$parse('sections.data').assign(scope.$parent, sections);
```

You can simply do this:

```
$parse('sections.data').assign(scope, sections);
```

Or, better yet just update it directly, like this:

```
scope.sections.data = sections;
```

Comment: `$parse('sections.data').assign(scope, sections);` this worked..
`scope.sections.data = sections;` this will not work because directive doesn't call for scope digestion, we have to call it explicitly. thanks!